# Use an exp-resso store coupon code without being a member

Tags: expresso-store, coupon-code

Is it possible to use an exp-resso store coupon code without being logged in / without being a member?

From the [docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/settings_promo_codes.html):

Restrict to Member Group: If configured, the promo code will only be able to be used by logged in members in this member group.

So I set the setting to 'all'. When I log out to test the code I get an error 'invalid code'. If I'm logged in, everything works shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a "per user limit" set for the promo code. Although it's not particularly clear, this by definition requires that a member be logged in, otherwise anonymous customers could easily get around the limit.

Comment: That's right! Thanks for the explanation.